# How to obtain client's URL from WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, url, soap

Here is the problem: I have a WCF service and a few sites connecting to it and sending certain messages.

How can I obtain client's URL (not IP) from the WCF service to assign it with the message? A kind of statistics.

I'm using C#.

Thank you in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Clients don't send from URLs, they send from IP addresses (well, callback clients have a URL but that's another story)